# Excel returning #VALUE! error when changing to array formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I have four subformulas concatenated into a larger formula:

```
=(IF(INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!F"&ROW())=0,(IFERROR(IF(FIND(".",INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!D"&ROW()))=2,INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!E"&ROW()),INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!D"&ROW())),INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!D"&ROW()))),INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!F"&ROW()))&" "&INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!H"&ROW())&" "&INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!I"&ROW())&" ("&INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!BH"&ROW())&")")
```

The formula works fine, but when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run as an array, I get a `#VALUE!` error that I can't explain.

When I break the formula up into the individual formulas being concatenated, each of them also returns its value fine, even when I then convert it to an array formula.

So far, I've been able to trace the error to the first subformula:

```
=(IF(INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!F"&ROW())=0,(IFERROR(IF(FIND(".",INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!D"&ROW()))=2,INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!E"&ROW()),INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!D"&ROW())),INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!D"&ROW()))),INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!F"&ROW())))
```

Both the `[value_if_true]` and the `[value_if_false]` can be turned into array formulas without a problem, but when I use them as conditions in an IF statement, I can't turn that IF statement into an array. Even if I blow them away and simply use 1 and 0 a, I still get `#VALUE!`.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. The "Row()" formula in the statement seems to be causing the "#VALUE!" error as an array formula within the "IF()" statement. After evaluating "ROW()", the row number is automatically surrounded by "{}" and carries over into the "INDIRECT(...)" formula, which it seems not to like.

I found a way around this issue by replacing the "ROW()" statement in the original formula with a reference to a cell having the row number I need. For example, your formula could be updated to:

```
=(IF(INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!F"&A1)=0,(IFERROR(IF(FIND(".",INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!D"&A1))=2,INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!E"&A1),INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!D"&A1)),INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!D"&A1))),INDIRECT("Lawmakers2017!F"&A1)))
```

... where cell A1 has the row number needed. You could place the "ROW()" formula in an adjacent column in the same row as your original formula and reference it.